# How to set the click area of an image and automatically change it with the size of the screen?JS implementation

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

How to divide an image into several regions, and the image will be proportionally scaled with changes in screen pixels. It is required that the clicking area should also be the same as the image,Please use JavaScript implementation，Thank you.

I have used the percentage method before, but its percentage also varies under different screen pixels,Here is my code

```
const PickArea = event => {
    x.value = event.offsetX
    y.value = event.offsetY
    const ClickX = event.offsetX / currentWidth.value
    const ClickY = event.offsetY / currentHeight.value
    if (ClickX >= 0.30 && ClickX <= 0.47 && ClickY >= 0.10 && ClickY <= 0.22) {
        flag[0] = !flag[0]
    }
    else if (ClickX >= 0.27 && ClickX <= 0.45 && ClickY >= 0.20 && ClickY <= 0.35) {
        flag[1] = !flag[1]
    }
    else if (ClickX >= 0.55 && ClickX <= 0.75 && ClickY >= 0.10 && ClickY <= 0.45) {
        flag[2] = !flag[2]
    }
    else if (ClickX >= 0.55 && ClickX <= 0.85 && ClickY >= 0.60 && ClickY <= 0.90) {
        flag[3] = !flag[3]
    }
    else if (ClickX >= 0.48 && ClickX <= 0.54 && ClickY >= 0.10 && ClickY <= 0.22) {
        flag[4] = !flag[4]
    }
    else if (ClickX >= 0.27 && ClickX <= 0.75 && ClickY >= 0.46 && ClickY <= 0.59) {
        flag[5] = !flag[5]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)